# how to access navigationOptions or title from child component

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'd like to access a route's `title`, as defined in `navigationOptions`, from a component on my screen, and I don't see how.  Am I going to have to shunt it through `navigationOptions.params`, and retrieve it with `props.navigation.getParam()`?